# Anaconda not importing package

Tags: anaconda

I am trying to use gmplot, which I've downloaded via Conda.

It is showing up in the environments, and the package is in /anaconda/pkgs, so the files are there.

But when I try to import it when running something (I've tried in Spyder and in Jupyter off Anaconda) it says No module called gmplot.

I've looked all over other questions but can't find anything that makes it work... have tried playing with PYTHONPATH manager to assign something specific to gmplot, but no luck.

If it's showing up clearly in the environments, is there something I'm not doing to get it to then be import-able?

Comment: What do you mean "downloaded via conda"? Could you state exactly what you did to "download" it?

Comment: conda install gmplot via terminal (am on Mac)

Comment: but you're using the Python interpreter from the conda environment, right?

Comment: Yes exactly, that's it.